# Is it possible to create a generic function that can take in either a UIView or UIButton as a parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to create a generic function that takes a generic T parameter but I want it to work for both a UIView and UIButton.  I'm not sure if this is possible.  Something like this:

```
 func changeUIColor<T>(item: T) {
        item.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

But I keep getting error:

> Value of type 'T' has no member 'backgroundColor'

any clue on how to get this to work?

Comment: Why not going for `extension` for `UIView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s unnecessary because UIButton inherits from UIView so a button is a view. If you were to write it it would look like this since both UIView and UIButton are UIViews (They also both inherit NSObject and UIResponder, so either of those could work too):

```
func someFunc<View: UIView>(someView: View) {}
```

In this case the conformance is a class and not a protocol and you can use polymorphism instead of a generic and just write:

```
func someFunc(someView: UIView)
```

And it will still take a UIButton.